# Sending raw emails with AWS SES using AWS SDK for Java v2

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I have been investigating on sending emails via AWS SES, especially on sending raw emails, not formatted ones.

I did my research and could see a lot of examples on sending raw emails using AWS SDK for Java v1, for instance [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/send-an-email-using-sdk-programmatically.html) or [here](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/example_code/ses). As the code base is using AWS SDK for Java v2, I cannot find any classes, APIs nor examples in v2.

There are some examples [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/java_ses_code_examples.html) with the titles or headings mentioning v2, but the code is actually v1, for instance, `SendRawEmailRequest` does not exist in v2.

[The documentation of SDK v2 SES API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference-V2/Welcome.html) does not have any methods for raw emails either.

My question is: Has AWS SDK for Java v2 just dropped sending raw emails? How would that justify AWS recommendations on upgrading the SDK from v1 to v2?

Answer (score 0):

After digging into the code, I've figured out, there is `RawMessage` class but it should be wrapped inside an `EmailContent` instead.

```java
    SdkBytes data = ...;
    
    RawMessage rawMessage = RawMessage.builder()
      .data(data)
      .build();
    
    EmailContent content = EmailContent.builder()
      .raw(rawMessage)
      .build();

    SendEmailRequest emailRequest =
      SendEmailRequest.builder()
        .fromEmailAddress(sender)
        .destination(destination)
        .content(content)
        .build();

    sesV2Client.sendEmail(emailRequest);
```